# Check value range from two numbers in javascript

Tags: javascript, numbers, range

I have two fields and a check made in javascript

```
<input type="text" id="numbers" />
<input type="text" id="via"  />



  if (((document.getElementById("via").value == "xxxx") && (document.getElementById("numbers").value == "10"))) 
....run my code
```

I want to check the input text "numbers" field and check if the value of the number is between 0 and 100 for example. So if it is between a range of numbers that I set.

and if I wanted to search only the odd or even numbers between 0 and 100?
How can I do?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please show your approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(parseInt(document.getElementById("numbers").value) > 0 && parseInt(document.getElementById("numbers").value) < 100) {
    // Do your thing
}
```

This should work (if the numbers are 0 and 100 of course).

**Edit:**

The code above would work 100% perfectly but I'd just like to show this approach as well (you probably won't use it though).

```
Number.prototype.between = function(a, b) {
    var min = Math.min.apply(Math, [a, b]),
    var max = Math.max.apply(Math, [a, b]);
    return this > min && this < max;
};
```

Usage:

```
if(parseInt(document.getElementById("numbers").value).between(0,10)) {
    // Do your thing
}
```

Comment: if I wanted to search only the odd or even numbers between 0 and 100?

Comment: Exactly what do you mean by that? As in searching 1,3,5,7?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare the value to a number, you must convert the test from the input field to a number. To do this, use the [`parseInt()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp) method.

Get the text value of the field, then convert it to a number.

```
<script>
var stringVal = document.getElementById("numbers").value;
var numericVal = parseInt(stringVal);

if ( numericVal > 0 && numericVal < 100 ) {

    // do something
}
</script>
```